# Nav link breaks onto new line when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create a navigation header for my site. It's arranged like this:

[image: nav header sketch]

I want it to be responsive when I shrink the browser size. I'm using `col-4` for each of the three columns in the navbar.

Once it reaches a certain size, though, the 3rd (last) link **drops onto a new line**.

I have each element centered within its respective `col-4` div, and I've set `margin: 15%` for the first two links.  How do I keep all three links on the same line when I shrink the viewport?

Here's the HTML for the page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="col-3 offset-1">
            <form style="width: 90%">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for someone..." aria-label="Search">
         </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="logo.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 nav-links">
                <a href="#" id="my-feed">MY FEED</a>
                <a href="#" id="hot">HOT</a>
                <a id="last-nav-link" href="#">MY PROFILE</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
```

Comment: You should post the HTML for your navbar. It'd help to know how the nav links are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Set padding instead of margin for spacing them, and have all the col's add up to total columns and no more. Not sure how bootstrap is set up but it's the margin causing the wrapping/line-breaking you're seeing.

If the total column width is 12 and you have 4 columns they must equal 12 when added up.

As Jacob said, post your HTML for the Nav. Without seeing the HTML we can only guess.